# selecting an item from listbox and using the name of the item later

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I'm making a small project using Python 3.4/5 in conjunction with Tkinter. I have make a list box that shows all items in a directory. I can't seem to find a way to select an item and then save the name in a variable for later use.

```
listnotes = Listbox(notebox, selectmode=SINGLE)
listnotes.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, padx=10, pady=10)
listnotes.insert(END, "notes")
for i in glob.glob("\TESTFOLDER\*.txt"):
    i = i[12:]
    listnotes.insert(END, i)
```

I have read around that using listnotes.get(ACTIVE) might work. Also i haven't been working with python for all that long, so any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use tkFileDialog to do this. One tkFileDialog option returns the file name  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) to do so,

For Ex:

```
listnotes.bind("<Return>", dosomething)   #to bind to your enterkey
```

and then the curselection method associated to the [Listbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm)

```
def dosomething(event):
    """
    on enter, capture the value from the Listbox 
    and assign the value captured to value via the get method form the selected value
    """
    try:
        selection = listnotes.curselection()
        value = listnotes.get(selection[0])

    except Exception as select:
        print("Nothing selected")
        pass
```